# How to fill a column if another column is not null in a dataframe using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Now I have a dataframe as following.

I want to create a column C and filled the cells in Column C with "x" if the cells in Column A is not null.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = pd.Series(['a', 'd'])
s2 = pd.Series([np.nan, 'e'])
s3 = pd.Series(['c', 'f'])
    
df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2), list(s3)],  columns =  ['A', 'B'])
df

    A   B
0   a   d
1   NaN e
2   c   f
```

Desired output:

```
    A   B  C
0   a   d  x
1   NaN e  NaN
2   c   f  x
```

I have tried my code and it is not working

```
df['C'] = np.nan
df[~df['A'].isnull()]['C'].replace(np.nan,'x',inplace=True)
df
```

Comment: `df.loc[~df['A'].isna(), 'C'] = 'x'`?

Comment: Yes, thanks @It_is_Chris. The code is working!

Comment: `df.assign(C=lambda dfa: np.where(~dfa["A"].isna(), "x", dfa["A"]))` another approach